# Pregunta relativa a si hay error o no hay error en la codificación de la base de datos de acuerdo a el resultado que obtengo al compilar el código?

Tags: compilar, transact-sql, microsoft-sql

Cuando microsoft SQL Server ejecuté el código que creé con Transact SQL para programar  mi base de datos y con eso lo compilé y me sale como resultado en la parte donde dice " Messages " varios  (1 row affected)
y Completion time: 2023-04-16T23:06:35.3300288-05:00 y absolutamente nada más; eso significa que m ibase de datos se hizó sin erroes o que tuvo errores ?

Comment: Terminó sin errores y afectó una fila. Fin